# C# Update a Dictionary<string,string> with LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to update my program settings, which are stored in a Dictionary.  Strangely enough if they were stored in a DatabaseContext the following function would work (I think), but since they are in a Dictionary I am getting a compiler error.  Why is my KeyValuePair.Value read only?  More importantly, how can I re-write the following function to actually update the Dictionary?

Thanks

```
public void putSetting(Dictionary<string, string> settings, string setting, string value)
{
  var qry = (from s in settings
             where s.Key == setting
             select s).Single();
   qry.Value = value; // Error  1 Property or indexer 
                      // 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>.Value'
                      // cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Quite honestly I would prefer writing the following:

```
settings[setting] = value;
```

instead of having this `putSetting` method which is deprived of any natural sense for existence. I must admit that I have seen many *things* during code reviews but this one is a winner.

Answer (score 5):

Not only is it correct that the `Value` is readonly, you also should consider that the `KeyValuePair` itself is a **struct** - so the `KeyValuePair` you have after your query is a new instance, not a reference to the one in the `Dictionary`.

---

I'm a bit confused why you are using linq for this?

For a `Dictionary<string,string>`you can just use:

```
 settings[setting] = value
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Value` of a `KeyValuePair` is always readonly. Note the decleration

```
public TValue Value { get; }
```

Use

```
settings[setting] = value;
```

instead. Seeing how short that is, I'm not sure what you're really gaining with this method.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with this approach.

- The type of `qry` is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.  This is a readonly struct which means you can't mutate it's properties.
- Additionally since it's a struct it's a copy of the struct inside the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  Even if you could mutate it it wouldn't update the value inside the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and hence wouldn't have an effect

What you're looking for here is the indexer on the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which allows for inserts of values for a given key

```
settings[setting] = value;
```

Comment: Thanks, you guys are rock stars!